# MAUI: Onappearing is not firing for RGPopup.Maui pages

Tags: maui

I am using the `RGPopup.Maui` for showing the pop-up pages in my MAUI application.

My problem is onappearing is not firing for RGPopup.Maui pop up pages.

Previously I have used `Rg.Plugins.Popup` in Xamarin Forms, but when I migrate to MAUI I started using the `RGPopup.Maui`. When I open the pop-up page the onappearing is not firing, Is it a known issue? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem in my project and I'm not sure it is a bug or not. But if you just want to override the OnAppearing method to do some work when the  PopupPage show you can try to override the `OnAppearingAnimationEnd` or the `OnAppearingAnimationBegin` method.

```
public class MyPopupPage :  RGPopup.Maui.Pages.PopupPage
{
    ...
    ...

    protected override void OnAppearingAnimationEnd()
    {
        base.OnAppearingAnimationEnd();
        // do some job
    }
    protected override void OnAppearingAnimationBegin()
    {
        base.OnAppearingAnimationBegin();
        //do some job
    }
}
```

I have tested the two method and they will be fired when the popup page display.

Comment: This issue is fixed on latest version (1.0.2)

https://github.com/microspaze/RGPopup.Maui/issues/1#issuecomment-1719022410